# OpenGl, язык C. Мировые координаты через gluUnProject и их сдвиг от glRotatef

Tags: c, opengl

Работаю с перспективной проекцией. Пытаюсь получить мировые координаты в месте клика мышью через функцию `gluUnProject()`. Но координаты смещаются из-за использования `glRotatef` и `glTranslatef` для движения "камеры".

С `glTranslatef` все понятно: просто отнять координаты, на которые смещаешь, а что делать с `glRotatef`?

Пока я не двигаю изображение при помощи `glRotatef`, все работает исправно, но вот с ним проблема.

На данный момент имею такую функцию:

```
glRotatef(-camera.xAngle, 1,0,0);
glRotatef(-camera.zAngle, 0,0,1);
glTranslatef(-camera_pos.x, -camera_pos.y, -camera_pos.z);

void ClientToOpenGlCoords(int x, int y, double *ox, double *oy, double *oz) {
    GLint vp[4];
    GLdouble mMatrix[16], pMatrix[16];
    float z;

    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, vp);
    y = vp[3] - y - 1;

    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mMatrix);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, pMatrix);
    glReadPixels(x, y, 1,1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &z);
    gluUnProject(x, y, z, mMatrix, pMatrix, vp, ox, oy, oz);
    *ox += camera_pos.x;
    *oy += camera_pos.y;
}
```

Пытался читать про матрицу MODELVIEW, но, видимо, моего понимания не хватает. Подскажите, что мне нужно использовать, чтобы учитывать сдвиг и от `glRotatef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен почему именно так работает, но пришел к такому решению:

```
glRotatef(-camera.xAngle, 1,0,0);
glRotatef(-camera.zAngle, 0,0,1);
glTranslatef(-camera_pos.x, -camera_pos.y, -camera_pos.z);

void ClientToOpenGlCoords(int x, int y, double *ox, double *oy, double *oz) {
    GLint vp[4];
    GLdouble mMatrix[16], pMatrix[16];
    float z;

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(-camera.xAngle, 1,0,0);
    glRotatef(-camera.zAngle, 0,0,1);
    glTranslatef(-camera_pos.x, -camera_pos.y, -camera_pos.z);

    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mMatrix);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, pMatrix);

    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, vp);
    y = vp[3] - y;


    glReadPixels(x, y, 1,1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &z);

    gluUnProject(x, y, z, mMatrix, pMatrix, vp, ox, oy, oz);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Ранее, при использовании функции, я использовал `glPushMatrix` и `glPopMatrix`, без них изображение сдвигалось при каждом нажатии мыши, сейчас я внес их в саму функцию, и добавил смещение камеры еще раз (так как матрицы получались единичные). Что интересно, без `glPushMatrix` и `glPopMatrix`, и заново перемещений камеры, не работает, ибо происходит смещение, видимо в вышеописанных функциях что-то меняет наши матрицы `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` и `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX`. Так что вот, что понял - расписал.